# Unable to display input after sending OTP - Ionic FirebaseX

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm using latest Ionic and FirebaseX (cordova-plugin-firebasex). I'm able to successfully send OTP to the entered mobile number. But for some reason, after sending the OTP i'm not able to enable to the OTP input and hide the GET OTP button.

My HTML:

```
    <ion-row class="ion-margin">
        <ion-col size="2" offset="1" class="phone-code">
            <ion-input disabled value="+91"></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="8" class="phone-number">
            <ion-input type="number" inputmode="numeric" [(ngModel)]="phonenumber" autofocus placeholder="Enter Phone Number"></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="ion-margin" #otpRow *ngIf="otpSent">
        <ion-col size="12" class="ion-text-center">
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="otp1val" #otp1 type="number" inputmode="numeric" required maxLength="1" (keyup)="otpController($event,otp2,'')" class="otp-input"></ion-input>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="otp2val" #otp2 type="number" inputmode="numeric" required maxLength="1" (keyup)="otpController($event,otp3,otp1)" class="otp-input"></ion-input>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="otp3val" #otp3 type="number" inputmode="numeric" required maxLength="1" (keyup)="otpController($event,otp4,otp2)" class="otp-input"></ion-input>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="otp4val" #otp4 type="number" inputmode="numeric"  required maxLength="1" (keyup)="otpController($event,otp5,otp3)" class="otp-input"></ion-input>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="otp5val" #otp5 type="number" inputmode="numeric"  required maxLength="1" (keyup)="otpController($event,otp6,otp4)" class="otp-input"></ion-input>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="otp6val" #otp6 type="number" inputmode="numeric"  required maxLength="1" (keyup)="otpController($event,'',otp5)" class="otp-input"></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="ion-margin">
        <ion-col size="8" offset="2" class="ion-text-center">
            <ion-button color="light" size="large" *ngIf="!otpSent" (click)="getOtp()" [disabled]="waitUp">{{otpBtnText}} <ion-spinner name="crescent" *ngIf="waitUp" color="danger"></ion-spinner></ion-button>
            <ion-button color="light" size="large" *ngIf="otpSent" (click)="verifyOtp()"> VERIFY </ion-button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

The GET OTP button, calls the following function:

```
getOtp(){
    alert("Get OTP Called");
    this.waitUp = true;
    this.otpBtnText = "SENDING ";
    var phoneRegex = /^[6-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/;
    if( (this.phonenumber) && (phoneRegex.test(this.phonenumber.toString())!=false) ) {
        console.log("Verifying Phone Number");
        this.fauth.verifyPhoneNumber((credential)=>{
            this.displayOtpInput();
            this.safecred = credential;
            alert("OTP Sent");
        }, (error) => {
            alert("Failed to verify phone number: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            this.waitUp = false;
            this.otpBtnText = "GET OTP";
        }, "+91"+this.phonenumber.toString(), 60);
    }else{
        alert("Invalid Mobile Number");
        this.waitUp = false;
        this.otpBtnText = "GET OTP";
    }
}
```

And finally the `displayOtpInput()` code is as follows:

```
displayOtpInput(){
    alert("Displaying OTP Input");
    this.otpSent = true;
    this.waitUp = false;
}
```

Complete TypeScript is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseX } from "@ionic-native/firebase-x/ngx";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  public phonenumber:number;
  public otp1val:number;
  public otp2val:number;
  public otp3val:number;
  public otp4val:number;
  public otp5val:number;
  public otp6val:number;
  public otpSent: boolean = false;
  public otpBtnText: string = "GET OTP";
  public verificationId: any;
  public safecred: any = {};
  public waitUp: boolean = false;
  constructor(public fauth: FirebaseX) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  displayOtpInput(){
    alert("Displaying OTP Input");
    this.otpSent = true;
    this.waitUp = false;
  }

  loginWithCred(){
    this.fauth.signInWithCredential(this.safecred, function() {
        alert("Successfully signed in");
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Failed to signin");
        console.error("Failed to sign in", error);
    });
  }

  verifyOtp(){
    alert("Verifying OTP");
    try{
        var otpCode = this.otp1val.toString() + this.otp2val.toString() + this.otp3val.toString() + this.otp4val.toString() + this.otp5val.toString() + this.otp6val.toString();
        this.safecred.code = otpCode;
        this.loginWithCred();
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        alert("Invalid OTP");
    }
    this.waitUp = false;
  }

  getOtp(){
    alert("Get OTP Called");
    this.waitUp = true;
    this.otpBtnText = "SENDING ";
    var phoneRegex = /^[6-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/;
    if( (this.phonenumber) && (phoneRegex.test(this.phonenumber.toString())!=false) ) {
        console.log("Verifying Phone Number");
        this.fauth.verifyPhoneNumber((credential)=>{
            this.displayOtpInput();
            this.safecred = credential;
            alert("OTP Sent");
        }, (error) => {
            alert("Failed to verify phone number: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            this.waitUp = false;
            this.otpBtnText = "GET OTP";
        }, "+91"+this.phonenumber.toString(), 60);
    }else{
        alert("Invalid Mobile Number");
        this.waitUp = false;
        this.otpBtnText = "GET OTP";
    }
  }
  otpController(event,next,prev){
   if(event.target.value.length < 1 && prev){
     prev.setFocus()
   }
   else if(next && event.target.value.length>0){
     next.setFocus();
   }
   else if(next == ""){
    this.verifyOtp();
   }
   else {
    return 0;
   } 
 }
}
```

I get all the alerts successfully (viz. "OTP Sent" and "Displaying OTP Input"), but the input is not being displayed. I tried creating a fake button to call the `displayOtpInput()` function directly upon clicking, and it works successfully. But only when this function is called within the `verifyPhoneNumber()` function, it displays the alert but the input is not displayed. I even tried alerting the value of `otpSent` and it shows `true`, but the OTP input is not shown, nor does the verify button display.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using promises in function that's why this happend.remove promises like asyn await.